# node.js + sequelize bulk insert

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, bulkinsert

I am new to node.js and sequelize. I have already built a mysql db with sequelize that matches my needs for the actual project.

Then I searched for possibilities to populate the db with sequelize, and the approach to combine it with csv files seem to be the best solution for me.

I have three csv files for three separate tables, and found Evan's script on github https://gist.github.com/evansiroky/167f218bb5342bff80c6#file-sequelizebulkinsert-js

Can anybody help me out how I need to implement it to do the job? I know that this must be a very basic question but I don't know how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to populate your DB with the data, you can still do it the old fashioned way, using mysql's mysqlimport or other tools.

If this is something that you will do frequently, maybe you can try creating a function that will call the sequelizeBulkInsert script, assuming it is working fine (not tested):

```
// sequelizeBulkInsert.js
var fs = require('fs');
var async = require('async');
var csv = require('csv');


module.exports = function(Model){
  this.importFile = function(filename, doneLoadingCallback) {
    var input = fs.createReadStream(filename);
    var parser = csv.parse({
      columns: true,
      relax: true
    });

    var inserter = async.cargo(function(tasks, inserterCallback) {
        Model.bulkCreate(tasks).then(function() {
            inserterCallback();
          }
        );
      },
      1000
    );

    parser.on('readable', function () {
      while(line = parser.read()) {
        inserter.push(line);
      }
    });

    parser.on('end', function (count) {
      inserter.drain = function() {
        doneLoadingCallback();
      }
    });

    input.pipe(parser);
  }
}
```

Then, in another file

```
var Bulk = require('/path/to/sequelizeBulkInsert');
var bulk = new Bulk(Model);

bulk.importFile('path_to_data.csv', function(){
  //data is imported
})
```

Comment: Thank you edujr. i've implemented it, and getting now an error that the model is not defined. Where do I define for which model sequelize has to interprete my csv data? Somewhere in inserter?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that. I've updated the code so you can pass your Model. Now the module will export a function. You might also have to change the cargo number (currently 1000) to match your needs

Comment: great, thank you Edujr, It's alreaddy late here :) i'll try tomorrow morning in the train to my work if i can call it from index.js in the models folder, or maybe even from the js file of the concerned model (i just need to populate 3 tables of 8).

Comment: hey Edujr, thank you very much. I can now populate my DB with the data, but it doesn't fill in one table the foreign keys. Is that possible with bulkcreate?